# eВопрос по Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

С помощью конструктора сайтов от Google создал «простенький» сайт (сайт учителя). Полтора месяца назад подключил на нём Google Analytics. Поначалу он выдавал «нормальную» статистику (небольшое количество пользователей, причем подавляющее большинство этих пользователей с одного города), а в последнее время количество пользователей резко возросло, и их география стала простираться по всему миру. При этом в разделе «Поведение» -> «Обзор» стали появляться следующие адреса запрашиваемых страниц:

/?from=http://get-your-social-buttons.info/?ref=56273338

(к сожалению, я новичок и не могу указывать более 1 ссылки)

При кликаньи на кнопку рядом с cсылкой открывается начальная страница сайта, хотя по идее должна открываться та страница сайта, что указана.
Вопрос: что это за посещения? Чем они вызваны? Можно ли сделать так, чтобы Google Analytics «отсекал» эти посещения?

Answer (score 2):

Это спам трафик, избавиться от него можно включив фильтр по домену в представлении. И лучше оставить еще один вид с полными данными